# Syntax Highlighting PHP SQL

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, syntax

I have a page that searches a database. I am looking to get the data that the user enters in the search box to be highlighted in the search results.

The data from the user is stored in the variable '$criteria', and all contents of that variable I am aiming to highlight.

My PHP looks as follows:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] != 1) {
    header("Location: ../");
}
include("../php_includes/connection.php");

$queryErrorMessage = "";
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search Tasks</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    <?php include("sidebar.php"); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="well well-lg">
                <h3>Search Tasks</h3>
                <hr>

                <form method="post" action="">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input name="criteria" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What would you like to search for?...">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
                        Submit
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>



 <?php 
            //Run section of code if the POST criteria is provided for "criteria"
            if(isset($_POST['criteria'])){
                $criteria = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['criteria']);
                //If the user does not provide criteria to search, an error will be displayed.
                if($criteria == ""){
                    $queryErrorMessage = "You did not provide any criteria";
                    GoTO errorMsg;
                }
                //Prepare sql statement checking each column with the criteria that is provided.
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM taskinfo WHERE clientCompany LIKE '%".$criteria."%' OR clientName LIKE '%".$criteria."%' OR email LIKE '%".$criteria."%' OR contactNo LIKE '%".$criteria."%' OR details LIKE '%".$criteria."%'";

                //Run sql query storing the records in $result
                if($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                        //Get each row and put it into the array $row
                        echo '<h4>Displaying results for search criteria: <b>'.$criteria.'</b></h4>';
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                            $queryErrorMessage = "";
                            //Display the query results
                            ?>

                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <h6><b>Task Details:</b></h6>
                                    <?php echo $row['details'];?>
                                    <h6><b>Task Information</b></h6>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Client Name: <?php echo $row['clientName'];?></li>
                                        <li>Email: <a href="mailto:<?php echo $row['email'];?>"><?php echo $row['email'];?></a></li>
                                        <li>Phone: <?php echo $row['contactNo'];?></li>
                                        <li>Posted by <b><?php echo $row['postedBy'];?></b></li>
                                        <li>Posted On: <b><?php echo $row['timeAdded']; ?></b></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            <?php   
                        }
                    } else {
                        $queryErrorMessage = "No records found with your criteria.";
                    }
                } else {
                    $queryErrorMessage = "Failed to perform query.";
                }
            }

            //Check if there is an error message
            //If true, echo the error to the user.
            //
            //Section of code is called errorMsg to 
            //Allow it to be called in the code above.
            errorMsg:
            if($queryErrorMessage != ""){
                echo 'An Error Occurred: ';
                echo $queryErrorMessage;
            }
            ?>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If anyone can help, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting correct values from the database?

Comment: why are you using LIKE against all of those columns? it doesn't make sense. Btw, you never said what the problem is. You're also not checking for errors

Comment: Yea everything gets returned fine. I am aware I'm not checking for errors, its still to be implemented.

Comment: Some of the columns I don't want to use when comparing the data from the user and the database, hence why I've specified them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this might help

```
    <?php echo preg_replace_callback('/'.$criteria.'/i', function($matches){
        return '<strong>' . $matches[0] . '</strong>';
    }, $row['clientName']); ?>
```

it would make the search keyword in the content bold

Comment: Thank you! So that would just go where I am echoing out the data then?